# Removing null productions from a context free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

```
X -> zZ|yW|WW
Y->Z
Z->X|ε
W->Y|X
```

Would I be right to think that as Y only Z as its terminal the ε moves to Y giving:

```
X -> zZ|yW|WW
Y->Z|ε
Z->X
W->Y|X
```

then?

```
X -> zZ|yW|WW|z
Y->Z
Z->X
W->Y|X
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the propagation of ε from Y in the w production.

```
X -> zZ|yW|WW|z
Y->Z
Z->X
W->Y|X|ε
```

which then moves up:

```
X -> zZ|yW|WW|z|y|ε
Y->Z
Z->X
W->Y|X
```

and continues:

```
X -> zZ|yW|WW|z|y
Y->Z
Z->X|ε
W->Y|X|ε
```

and we are back we are we started! This grammar can never be written without ε.

(Unless someone wants to correct me?)